# Count the amount of a specific number (1) in a 4 digit number

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a program where it asks the user to enter a number of 4 digits, and then the program will ready how many times the number "1" is repeated in the chosen digit. I have no idea how to make the program read the amount of 1's and then output the amount, any ideas please? Thank you.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int num;

    cout << "Ingrese un numero de 4 digitos porfavor. " << endl; //Enter a 4 digit number
    cin >> num;

    if (num > 999 & num < 10000) {
        // count how many 1's the number has

    } else {
        cout << "El numero que usted ha ingresado no tiene unicamente 4 digitos." << endl; //The number you chose doesnt have only 4 digits. (more/less than)
    }


}
```

Comment: FYI, `&` needs to be `&&` in this case

Comment: @RemyLebeau luckily, for boolean values `&` is the same as `&&` :)

Comment: You cannot do any input correctly unless you validate the stream-state after the input and before you attempt to use the value, e.g.  `if (!(std::cin >> num)) { std::cerr << "error: invalid integer input.\n"; return 1; }`

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to read the number as a `std::string` instead of an `int` (or at least convert the `int` to `std::string` with [`std::to_string()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)), and then use [`std::count()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) to count the `'1'` characters.

```
if (num > 999 && num < 10000) {
    std::string s = std::to_string(num);
    int numOnes = std::count(s.begin(), s.end(), '1');
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to continually divide the number by 10, and checking whether the last digit is 1:

```cpp
int numOnes = 0;
int temp = num;
while (temp > 0) {
    if (temp % 10 == 1) numOnes++;
    temp = temp / 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest Way Of Doing

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num, temp, rem, count = 0;
    cout << "Enter 4 digit number:";
    cin >> num;
    temp = num;
    while (temp != 0)
    {
        rem = temp % 10;
        if (rem == 1)
        {
            count++;
        }
        temp = temp / 10;
    }
    cout << "The number of 1 in the four digit number " << num << " = " << count;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You must VALIDATE the input, e.g. `if (!(std::cin >> num)) { std::cerr << "error: invalid integer input.\n"; return 1; }`

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.